# How to respond to AJAX POST request in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to have my google chrome extension send data to my ruby on rails site using Ajax and am having trouble figuring out what is happening here:

I see that my rails server has received the data (two arrays) I'm sending but there is a 404? And then I have an error about user id?

```
Started POST "/add_service" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-24 00:34:37 +0800
Processing by UsersController#add_service as HTML
  Parameters: {"urlArray2"=>["0.0.0.0", "item.jd.com", "stackoverflow.com", "www.google.com.hk"], "countArray2"=>["3670", "20", "2", "2"]}
  User Load (11.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 13ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find User without an ID:
...
...
```

This is the Ajax from my Chrome extension:

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "JSON",    
    url: "http://0.0.0.0:3000/add_service",
    data: ({'urlArray2':urlArray2,'countArray2':countArray2}),
    success: function(){
        //alert("Web services loaded into ConsultFred.");
    }
});
```

This is my user controller:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:add_service]
...
...
def add_service
  logger.debug "This is working..."
  #@user = current_user
  #@user.sitearray = params[:urlArray2]
  repsond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to root_url }
     format.json { redirect_to root_url }
  end
end
```

My routes.rb (edit: added more info):

```
  resources :users, :only => [:index, :show, :edit, :update ] do
    post :share_to_linkedin, on: :member
  end

  post 'add_service', to: 'users#add_service'
```

[EDIT Jan 24th]

Looking at the AJAX response right now, it is in fact a problem with the parameters and not providing the user.id number:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /add_service
============================================
> Couldn't find User without an ID
```

How can I possibly be able to send it though? The ajax request is external from a chrome extension?

Comment: Where do you set the current_user variable? Because if you are trying to access from outside the current_user variable may not be set.

Comment: current_user is a helper method in the ApplicationController. I think the problem I have right now is that the first line of the method logger.debug "This is working..." isn't even being executed?

Comment: @MarkoJurinčič You are right! How would I solve this problem though? The chrome extension (from outside) doesn't know enough...

Comment: You could add an additional parameter user_id to the post parameters and then just user = User.find(params[:user_id])...Also I am using the Advance Rest client to test rest communication (posting parameters)

Comment: @MarkoJurinčič the problem is the ajax post request is coming from a chrome extension and it does not have any knowledge of user_id. Maybe my chrome extension needs to login to my rails site so that it can obtain the user_id? If so, whats a good way to go about that?

Comment: If you have the user credentials to login I would create a simple rest comunication. 1. You send the user credentials to the page login and the controller must respond with a json with the user id (respond to json format)...2. then in the extension you parse the json response and get out of it the user_id. Now you have the id and repost to the server. Add a little security (at least https) and it should be it.

Comment: @MarkoJurinčič How can i make this login seamless? Since the user is already logged into my rails site before the chrome extension is called I guess its possible to automatically login the chrome extension via ajax? I will try this...

Comment: Well, you can try setting a coockie with some data that can help the extension to get some data from the user, but you still need some validation to get things more secure.

Answer (score 0):

I think these lines hold the key for you:

```
User Load (11.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Completed 404 Not Found in 13ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find User without an ID
```

Looks like you're not passing the parameter to your query correctly. That `$1` should have been passed as the actual value to the SQL statement.

Comment: You're right. However, the AJAX is sent from a chrome extension, so I don't really have any other parameters to send...

Comment: This is an example of UserController when its working, no difference -> Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  User Load (51.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

Comment: In which case, rather than the syntax being the problem, the content of $1 in your broken example must be empty. One way or another, rails is not being given an ID to find the User with.